# Test data before loop each

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like test data before start my loop.

```
  {{#if messages}}
    <ul class="no-bullet list-admin">
    {{#each messages}}
      {{> messageItemAdmin}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{else}}
   No message
  {{/if}}
```

But this don't work.

Do you have any idea ? Do you think i need create helpers ?

I return data with Iron Router, not on helpers.

Thank you !

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Do you want to filter out objects in the loop that don't meet the test? Or do you simply want to hide the bullet list if there are no items?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the 'messages' variable contains a cursor, which will always evaluate to true.

The way to go is thus to create a helper which checks if the count() of the cursor is larger then 0

for example:

```
Template.messageList.helpers({
  isEmpty(){
    const query = { ... };
    return Messages.find(query).count() > 0
  }
```